# How we can change variable of protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I have two class that implemented from same protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol{

}
class MyFirstClass : MyProtocol{
    var test : Int = 0
}
class MySecondClass : MyProtocol{
    var test : Int = 0
}
```

How can I have a function that increase test variable each time I pass object of MyFirstClass or MySecondClass

something like this

```
var a = MyFirstClass()
var b = MySecondClass()

func inc(myObject : MyProtocol){
    myObject.test ++ // myObject has no member `test`
}

inc(a)
inc(a)
inc(b)
inc(a)
```

Comment: You can add concrete functions to an `extension` of the protocol. I think that is what you need to look into, but I'm not sure if I've fully understood your question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the complete Swift 3 code:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
   var test: Int { get set }
}

class MyFirstClass: MyProtocol {
    var test: Int = 0
}

class MySecondClass: MyProtocol {
    var test: Int = 0
}

func inc(_ obj: MyProtocol) {
    obj.test += 1
}

var a = MyFirstClass()
var b = MySecondClass()

inc(a)
print(a.test) // 1
inc(a)
print(a.test) // 2
inc(b)
print(b.test) // 1
inc(a)
print(a.test) // 3
```

Important note:

I've made MyProtocol `class` only, as this allow code optimization.

If you want it to any type (not only classes), you can adopt [**@Hamish** solution](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57c82141688f27dd6f430c71) (you can read more about this in the comments below)

Comment: Just because `MyProtocol` isn't class bound (`: class`), doesn't mean that instances of `MyFirstClass` or `MySecondClass` will be copied when passed to the `inc(_:)` function – they will still have reference semantics (e.g Writing the function as `func inc(_ obj: MyProtocol) {var obj = obj; obj.test += 1}` would still work in this case). Making `MyProtocol` class bound restricts conforming types to be classes, and therefore allows the compiler to treat instances typed as `MyProtocol` as reference types – therefore allowing you to mutate a member on `obj` in the function directly.

Comment: I understand what you mean, however: your example ``func inc(_ obj: MyProtocol) {var obj = obj; obj.test += 1}`` will not change the original instance. From what I see, OP wants to change the original instance. What you said about constraining the protocol is true, and since OP used two classes as an example, I felt OK answering the way I did (it also makes sense performance-wise constraining it, if you will use it on classes only).

Comment: My example would change the `test` property on the original instance ([feel free to try it out for yourself](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57c82141688f27dd6f430c71)). I agree that in this case it indeed makes perfect sense for the protocol to be class bound, I'm just disagreeing with the part of your answer that says "*otherwise, when you invoke the `inc(_:)` function you will pass a copy of your `MyFirstClass`/`MySecondClass` instance*"

Comment: Ohhh now we're in the same page! You're completely right, let me update the answer, thanks for pointing this out!